# Loading images with matchMedia and data-src

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any simple way to make images linked into the html document with data-src visible with matchMedia in JS?

For example, I'm working on a website, making it responsive. I have some images i don't want to load on the smallest screen size to avoid longer loading times.

Comment: For this you'd use the `srcset` attribute or the `picture` tag. Neither are very widely supported.

Comment: That would be add/remove then? Since they aren't supported, is there any other way to go about?